# Debugging *** glibc detected *** python: realloc(): invalid next size without Valgrind

Tags: python, c, debugging, memory, glibc

I'm running a server-script in Python, and I'm getting a `*** glibc detected *** python: realloc(): invalid next size` error every once in a while. I can't debug it with Valgrind, as it won't let me run the script continuously as a server while profiling (?).

From what I understand, this is an underlying C issue, which means that one of my C-libraries must be the culprit?

These are my imports:

```
import tornadoredis
import tornado
from tornado import web
from tornado import websocket
from tornado import httpserver
from tornado import ioloop
from tornado import auth
import tornado.gen
from time import sleep
import logging
import tornado.escape
import simplejson as json
import urllib
import random
import string, re
import xmlrpclib
import urllib2
import os, sys, time, zlib
import cjson                            # C
from collections import Counter
import pygeoip
import redis                            # C?
```

I'm also running another script with among other things a `lxml` module which is hard at work. Could it be that this module messes with the memory of a module in my first script, triggering a memory error in the first script?

Could this error be caused by a `dict` in Python that is overfilled?

Could it be a bug in Python 2.7?

Any help on debugging and fixing this would be greatly appreciated! If any more info needed, let me know, I'll add as much as I can.